# Sql - data reference does not exist when comparing two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables - `artist and album`

columns in `artist - id, name, artist_genre`

columns in `album - id, name, artist_name, album_genre, release_date`

I would like to find all artists in the album table that is not in the genre listed in artist table (to be more specific - if artist X has genre ‘pop’ and ‘rock’ registered but produce an album Y with genre ‘classic’, then the artist, album and genre should be listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select artist_name, name, album_genre 
from album left join artist on artist.name = album.artist_name and album_genre = artist_genre 
where artist.id is null
```

Comment: Cheers Tomas! It did not quite work out. I've got a solution from Upendra. Thanks!

Comment: @user3168017 : As per my view Thomas's answer is much better than my answer as per performance, cause join is much faster than sub query.

Comment: I've tried it again and get this working. You're right upendra, Tomas' solution works better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
select artist_name, name, album_genre 
from album alb
where album_genre not in (select distinct artist_genre 
                          from  artist 
                          where name = alb.artist_name)
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4edd3/1)**

Comment: Thanks Upendra! That's just what I needed. I tried with 'not exist' first but could not get it working. Much appreciated.

Comment: Upendra, +1 for fair play! :-)

Answer (score 0):

What about this..

```
"SELECT artist_name FROM album, artist WHERE artist_name = name AND album_genre != album_genre";
```